# Error message while loading an image to mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

Code:

```
import pymongo, gridfs
client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.gridfs_example
fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
fs.list()
fs.put(open('C:\\Users\\Mihir\\Desktop\\Python with web interface\\crap\\Capture.PNG', 'r'), filename = 'images')
```

Error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 19: character maps to <undefined>
```

I tried searching for web with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with images, try to open their bytes, use **"rb"** instead of **"r"**:

```
fs.put(open('C:\\Users\\Mihir\\Desktop\\Python with web interface\\crap\\Capture.PNG', 'rb'), filename = 'images')
```

Python is trying to convert the image bytes into string